# Условие - переменная не равна одному из значения из списка

Tags: php

Помогите составить короткое условие по плану:

- имеется переменная $a
- значение переменной не должно быть равно из списка (яблоко, груша, арбуз).

Значений в списке много - например 500.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пример:

```
$arr = ['one', 'two', 'three'];
$val = 'two';
if(in_array($val, $arr) === FALSE){
 // code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$arr = ['one', 'two', 'three'];
$val = 'two';
if(!in_array($val, $arr)){
 // code
}
```

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]